# How remote control applications are made

Tags: android

I'm interested in creating application that will allow to control some household appliances. I've seen some applications like Ready For Sky that can do this. How are these applications are made? Is there any kind of API for this or any direction in which I should dig?

Comment: this question is too broad. which specific feature do you want to implement?

Comment: @Doc For instance, I want to turn on/off the heater or control it's temperature and later I could make some schedule for it.